# What is master class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am beginner in .NET . What is Master Class in C#? Can anyone explain it briefly ? I could not find properly describe anywhere. Now this is my assignment and I can't understand what is actually master class. Is this is related with inheritance?

Comment: Why not a googling?

Comment: I googled,but become confused that's why I ask here

Comment: are you sure it's master and not base ?

Comment: MasterClass Or Master Page or masterclass for office development?  We need more context.  Ask your instructor, it is their job to explain it to you.

Comment: @Dani , yes I am sure. He said to me MasterClass. :( I am totally new in this site, I can't understand.

Comment: In this case, i think it should not tag `asp.net-mvc` but instead `asp.net webforms`. You can read Dai's answer for more information about master.class. But. in shourt, may be just understand it, as a page that will be call every time you open a page in your site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"master class" itself is not a technical term in the C# developer ecosystem.

In the ASP.NET WebForms world, `.master`  and `master=""` refers to the "Master page" which is a file which defines markup that surrounds an `.aspx` file. The Razor equivalent is a `Layout` file. Each master page has its own class (generated by compiling the `.master` file into a `MasterPage` subclass at runtime) which is a "master page class".

In object-oriented programming in general, a "master class" *could* refer to some common base class used in a particular context - this could refer to `System.Object` - the type from which all reference-types in .NET ultimately derive from, however the term "superclass" tends to be preferred.

A possible, but unlikely, explanation is it refers to some programmer who retains excellent programming ability and regularly promulgates their knowledge: as having "master-class", though this is unlikely as you're refering to a C# context.

Finally, the person who used those words when talking to you or writing some article could just be devoid of actual knowledge and is pulling words out of their nether-regions :)

Comment: I'm going to go with your last suggestion, Dai :-)